# Is there a way to change the default blue color of the Google maps API?

Tags: ios, google-maps

In iPhone app, the Google maps API looks like this, is there any way to change it to black?

[image]

Comment: What part do you want to change to black?

Comment: that is not the google maps api ... that is the browser..

Answer (score 0):

If using Google's Maps API for JavaScript, use a StyledMap to change the colors:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#StyledMaps

Google even provides a wizard that generates the right JavaScript code for you while you experiment with different settings to get the ones you like:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

I'm not sure if and how any of this translates to maps generated with objective-C APIs inside of iOS, but the screenshot in your question looks like a browser window so hopefully this will work for you.